# SSD to Lenovo Y560 and G780 optical drive slot

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, lenovo-laptop, optical-drive

I have a Lenovo G780 laptop and my friend has a Lenovo Y560 laptop, we thought about replacing the useless optical drives with an SSD.

I have found a great [blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/04/best-of-both-worlds-putting-an-ssd-in-your-optical-bay/) about it but I still have some questions regarding these models.

As you may understand, SSD will serve as a system drive for OS and some programs and the HDD will remain as a storage drive for files and documents, thus, I have a question - will there  be any difference in performance if I install SSD in the ODD slot or replace the HDD inside the laptop with SSD and install the HDD to ODD slot? If there is no difference, then the downside of replacing the HDD with an SSD is that there is a warranty sticker on the bottom of the laptop that is covering one of the screws that allow opening the laptop. The upside is that in case of emergency if the OS fails and there will be problems with installing/repairing it with an USB drive, I could easily switch the HDD in ODD with a CD-ROM.

As I have checked, both laptops have a SATA bus in ODD, but I'm not sure what bus is used for connecting the current HDD's in both laptops. Maybe someone can answer that too. I have found [this](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_g480_g485_g580_g585_g780_hmm_v1.0_english.pdf) manual for G780.

And the other question is: I've read somewhere that some of the 17.3" laptops and some other laptops already have space for a secondary HDD/SSD, does any of the mentioned laptops have it?

## EDIT:

OK, I decided to update this post only to say that I am currently having my Win7 on optical drive in the CD-ROM bay with no problems for about 3 or 4 months. No performance or stability issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both laptops interfaces are SATA and CD/DVDs are using same controller as main HDD so there is no downside in performance.

As for warranty problem, you can ask authorized service to replace hdd for you.

On the other hand if you're not planning to use cd/dvd again, then you can install your system on ssd in dirvebay. In case of problems with system, you can use usb stick to recover.